# wglCreateContextAttribsARB function crashes

Tags: c++, opengl, openglcontext

I try to write down code from this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yWJGDAzHg8&feature=youtu.be&annotation_id=annotation_555668999&feature=iv&src_vid=5LVZqH4_4Wo). I have the code of InitializeOGL():

```
bool Ogl::InitializeOGL(bool vSync)
{
  cout<<"Init OpenGL"<<endl;
  int pixelFormat;
  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelFormatDescriptor;
  int result;
  char *vendorChar, *rendererChar;

  hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
  if(!hDC)
    return false;

  pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pixelFormatDescriptor);
  if(pixelFormat==0)
    return false;

  result = SetPixelFormat(hDC,pixelFormat,&pixelFormatDescriptor);
  if(result!=1)
    return false;

  HGLRC tempDeviceContext = wglCreateContext(hDC);
  wglMakeCurrent(hDC,tempDeviceContext);

  // glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK)
    return false;

  int attribList[5] = 
  {
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 1, 0
  };

  hGLRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC,0,attribList);
  if(hGLRC!=NULL)
  {
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(tempDeviceContext);
    result = wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hGLRC);
    if(result!=1)
      return false;
  }

  vendorChar = (char*)glGetString(GL_VENDOR);
  rendererChar = (char*)glGetString(GL_RENDERER);

  strcpy_s(videoCardInfo,vendorChar);
  strcat_s(videoCardInfo,"-");
  strcat_s(videoCardInfo,rendererChar);

  if(vSync)
    result = wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);
  else
    result = wglSwapIntervalEXT(0);

  if(result!=1)
    return false;

  int glVersion[2] = {-1,-1};
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION,&glVersion[0]);
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION,&glVersion[1]);

  cout<<"Initializing OpenGL"<<endl;
  cout<<"OpenGL version"<<glVersion[0]<<"."<<glVersion[1]<<endl;
  cout<<"GPU"<<videoCardInfo<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to change context version to OpenGL 3.1, here crashes *wglCreateContextAttribsARB()*
function (Pointer for this is getting in *LoadExtensions()* correctly). When I try to create OpenGL 4.0 here crashes function *wglSwapIntervalEXT()*. My graphic card handles only OpenGL 3.1.

My question is how to succefully init OpenGL context here? What I have to do to create OpenGL context in version 3.1.

Comment: I think it is a very bad idea to use a completely uninitialized `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR`.

Comment: You also cannot change the pixel format for a Device Context (you are using the one bound to your window in this case) after you have selected a pixel format. ***This*** is the reason that everyone uses a  second window when setting up the pixel format using the ARB function. It may return a different pixel format, in which case you are stuck with the format you used when you initialized your extensions (which, in this case, could be any random format - most likely a GDI format that does not support OpenGL since your PFD is uninitialized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need to be mentioned here:

#### 1. Driver Version

If your graphics card / driver only support OpenGL 3.1, then `WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB` and friends are generally going to be undefined. Before OpenGL 3.2 introduced core / compatibility, context versions were not particularly meaningful.

- This requires support for either `WGL_ARB_create_context` or `WGL_ARB_create_conext_profile`.

#### 2. Incorrect usage of `ChoosePixelFormat` and `SetPixelFormat`

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelFormatDescriptor; // <--- Uninitialized
```

At minimum, the Win32 API needs you to initialize the size field of this structure. In years past, the size of structures was used to determine the version of Windows that a particular piece of code was written for. These days structures like `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` are generally static in size because they are used by a part of Windows that is deprecated (GDI), but if you do not set the size you can still thoroughly confuse Windows. Furthermore, you need to flag your pixel format to support OpenGL to guarantee that you can use it to create an OpenGL render context.

Also note that once you set the pixel format for a device context on Windows, it cannot be changed. Generally, this means if you want to create a dummy render context to initialize your extensions you should also create a dummy window with a dummy pixel format. **After** you initialize your extensions, you can use `wglChoosePixelFormatARB (...)` and its associated functions to select the pixel format for your main window's device context.

This is (***was***) particularly important back in the days before FBOs when you wanted to implement multi-sampling. You cannot get a multi-sample pixel format using `ChoosePixelFormat (...)`, but you need to call `ChoosePixelFormat (...)` to setup the extension necessary to get a multi-sample pixel format. Kind of a catch 22.

Comment: My card fortunately supports WGL_ARB_create_context extension. I tried to zero PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR struct and it works! Thanks!